# testing a class with a propel query as input

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, propel

I want to unittest a class that consumes a propel model or criteria object as input.

As this is a Symfony2 bundle without any model of it's own i'd like to think I could use use a class mimicking either input type and provide getters and setters that return static values.

Is this possible and does anyone have any experience in how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question right, you simply want a Stub:

```
class PropelModelStub {
    public $someparam;

    private someMethod(){
        // ..
    }
}
```

The stub should implement all methods used in your class and somehow track whats happening. This depends on your class and what you want to test. You can track the usage of a method or the attributes passed to a function.

Simply usage in a test:

```
public function testMyClass(){
    $stub = new PropelModelStub();
    $classToTest = new MyClass($stub);
    classToTest->whatever();

    $this->assertEquals('ValueIExpect', $stub->someparam);
}
```

Here you pass the Stub into your class and then use this class as you would in your code. Afterwards you check if the Stub has the correct values.

**PHPUnit build in stubs**

If your PropelModel always extends from some base class, you can use phpunit to create your mock. This makes things way easier and also reduces the code:

```
$stub = $this->getMock('\\Namespace\\of\\PropelModel');
$stub ->expects($this->once())
->method('someMethod')
->will($this->returnValue(1));
```

See [here](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/test-doubles.html) for more information about this.